# Heroku Private Space and VPC Peering connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, ip-address, amazon-vpc

Heroku introduced  [Heroku Private Spaces](https://www.heroku.com/private-spaces) . This resolves one of the problems related to my service running on AWS. I can now add the IPs of the dynos running in private space in the AWS security group to whitelist them. 
But, now I was thinking of directly using the private IP of my service instead of using the public IP. So, is it possible to add a VPC Peering Connection ( [VPC Peering](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html) ) between the VPC where my service is running and between the VPC where the Heroku private space is created?

If this works then it will be really great. If this is possible, how to know the VPC where the private space is created?

Comment: Spaces is a beta product - you'd be better using official Heroku support channels to get a response here.

Comment: Thanks. Will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a late answer since comments aren't accurate any longer. Heroku Private Spaces now support [VPC peering.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-space-peering). The relevant caveats from the documentation:

- Connections to web processes in a Private Space on appname.herokuapp.com or a custom domain name are made over the public Internet, not the peering connection.
- You can only connect to IP addresses in your VPC that are part of the primary CIDR block. If you have added secondary CIDR blocks to your VPC, they will not be reachable from the Private Space.
- You can connect from your VPC to dynos in the Private Space, but you must know the IP address in advance. Dynos do not have public DNS records.
- You cannot connect directly to data services such as Postgres, Kafka or Redis in the private space from the peered VPC.
- Dynos cannot connect directly to other networks that are peered to your VPC. Instead, you need to run a proxy or load-balancing service inside your VPC to enable such connections.
- You can peer up to 5 AWS VPCs to a private space. Open a support ticket if you need to peer more than 5 VPCs to your private space.